# Iterating over all integer vectors summing up to a certain value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector

I would like to find a clean way so that I can iterate over all the vectors of positive integers of length, say `n` (called `x`), such that `sum(x) == 100` in MATLAB.

I know it is an exponentially complex task. If the length is sufficiently small, say 2-3 I can do it by a `for` loop (I know it is very inefficient) but how about longer vectors?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As you say, it's exponential. If you avoid the `for` loop you will be generating all vectors at once, and you will soon encounter memory limitations.

Comment: It's not actually exponential - the scaling law is approx `n^k` as `n` goes to infinity, for vectors of length `k` that sum to `n`.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Yes, I meant exponential in vector length

Comment: Mmm, you're probably right!

Comment: @PBM When you say *integer vectors*, what exactly do you mean? Is it that all their elements are integers or *positive* integers? If it's the former, you'll have an infinite number of solutions... if it's the latter, then it's a variant of the knapsack problem, with the complexity of _O(n*sum)_.

Comment: @EitanT I meant the positive integers. I should have been more precise. Sorry!

Comment: @PBM So it can be reduced to a knapsack problem, where you have a set of 101 possible items (0-100), and you need to find all subsets the sum of which equals 100. This is a classic problem that can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time using dynamic programming.

Comment: @EitanT I think a slight difference is that I am looking for all subsets of size `n` such that their sum is equal to 100. Am I right?

Comment: @PBM Yes, but looks like the same logic can be applied here. I suggest that you read this related question: [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty method that uses recursion. The idea is that to generate all vectors of length `k` that sum to `n`, you first generate vectors of length `k-1` that sum to `n-i` for each `i=1..n`, and then add an extra `i` to the end of each of these.

You could speed this up by pre-allocating `x` in each loop.

Note that the size of the output is (*n* + *k* - 1 choose *n*) rows and *k* columns.

```
function x = genperms(n, k)

if k == 1
    x = n;
elseif n == 0
    x = zeros(1,k);
else
    x = zeros(0, k);
    for i = 0:n
        y = genperms(n-i,k-1);
        y(:,end+1) = i;
        x = [x; y];
    end
end
```

---

**Edit**

As alluded to in the comments, this will run into memory issues for large `n` and `k`. A streaming solution is preferable, which generates the outputs one at a time. In a non-strict language like Haskell this is very simple -

```
genperms n k
    | k == 1    = return [n]
    | n == 0    = return (replicate k 0)
    | otherwise = [i:y | i <- [0..n], y <- genperms (n-i) (k-1)]
```

viz.

```
>> mapM_ print $ take 10 $ genperms 100 30
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,99]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,98]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,97]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,96]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,95]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,94]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,93]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,92]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,91]
```

which runs virtually instantaneously - no memory issues to worry about.

In Python you could achieve something nearly as simple using generators and the `yield` keyword. In Matlab it is certainly possible, but I leave the translation up to you!

Comment: "quick" is something this solution is definitely not :)

Comment: Haha. I meant "quick to write" rather than "quick to run" :) There are certainly implementation details that can speed it up, but I don't think there's a better algorithm (this method generates the minimum number of vectors required to solve the problem, as opposed to generate-and-reject algorithms which will consider many more vectors than are required).

Comment: It can run into memory issues though :)

Comment: Oh, absolutely. If `n` and `k` are large you'll need to do something else. A generate-and-reject algorithm would be simplest, though slow. I'd need to think a little harder to come up with a solution that efficiently generates the vectors one at a time (it'd be much easier in a non-strict language!).

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible method to generate all vectors at once (will give memory problems for moderately large `n`):

```
s = 10; %// desired sum
n = 3; %// number of digits
vectors = cell(1,n);
[vectors{:}] = ndgrid(0:s); %// I assume by "integer" you mean non-negative int
vectors = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) reshape(c,1,[]), vectors, 'uni', 0).');
vectors = vectors(:,sum(vectors)==s); %// each column is a vector
```

Now you can iterate over those vectors:

```
for vector = vectors %// take one column at each iteration
    %// do stuff with the vector
end
```

---

To avoid memory problems it is better to generate each vector as needed, instead of generating all of them initially. The following approach iterates over all possible `n`-vectors in one `for` loop (regardless of `n`), rejecting those vectors whose sum is not the desired value:

```
s = 10; %// desired sum
n = 3;; %// number of digits
for number = 0: s^n-1
    vector = dec2base(number,s).'-'0'; %// column vector of n rows
    if sum(vector) ~= s
        continue %// reject that vector
    end
    %// do stuff with the vector
end
```